# Will Gnome Disk Utility "overwrite existing data with zero" repair bad sector?

Tags: hard-drive

Can I repair my old hard disk (which I don't know whether it got bad sectors or not) simply by using slow format (Overwrite existing data with zero) in Gnome Disk Utility?

Comment: Physical damage cannot be repaired by formatting. Formatting the disk will mark bad sector as bad, so that those sectors are not used. If the disk is falling you will get new bad sectors. If the disk has failed formatting won't fix it.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `Disks` **SMART Data & Tests** window. It may take 2 screenshots to get all of the data.

Comment: Hi, user68186, I used to repair bad sectors in windows using chkdsk command. I wonder if it work the same way as overwrite existing data with zero or not. Hi, heynnema, for unknown reason, the SMART data & tests greyed out. I wonder how to active it.

Comment: When responding to users, start comments with @heynnema (using me as an example), or the other users will probably never see your reply. Install `smartmontools` and `gsmartcontrol` and see if you can get SMART data that way. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...